# Angular material - autocomplete - Filtering results with groups

Tags: html, angular, autocomplete, angular-material, mat-form-field

I am trying to create a simple dropdown using material autocomplete and I stuck. I have a few issues here:

1. When I choose an option I see its id and I need to see name instead.
   ID is used in event emitter and backend - I tried to use [displayWith] but inside function, I still get only ID and not the whole object which I can map after.
2. I would like to be able to filter results but I have groups that can
   have no ID or Name but maybe there is a way to filter only using mat-option values?

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "tableItems": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Paul"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Mary"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "tableItems": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Brian"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Joseph"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "Luke"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My HTML component looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Results</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    placeholder="Type to filter results"
    type="text"
    [formControl]="control"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    spellcheck="false"
  >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-optgroup
      *ngFor="let group of groups"
      [label]="group.name"
      [class.mat-optgroup-no-label]="!group.name"
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of group.tableItems;"
        [value]="option.id"
      >
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Point 1 was resolved. I didn't pass the whole object in `[value]` but still need help with filtering.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on this point.
I would like to be able to filter results but I have groups that can have no ID or Name but maybe there is a way to filter only using mat-option values?
Also please post on what you tried with displayFn?

Comment: @ParthasarathyK I have groups as you see in JSON. Each group has ID and Name but sometimes like in the attached example groups have empty IDs and Names so I would like to be able to filter using only mat-option names - ```{{option.name}}``` I basically need filter function/observable for this example. 
I did try something like this: ```<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">``` and then ```displayFn(option) { console.log(option.name); }``` returned me undefined and if I console log only option I get ID not whole object. Should I see whole object there?

Comment: @ParthasarathyK Ok I made a mistake with ```[displayWith]``` because I didn't pass the whole object as the value. I did ```[value]="option.value"``` instead of ```option```